# Why RIP(Routing Information Protocol ) uses hopcount of 15 hops?

Tags: networking

I'm reading one of the Distance vector protocol RIP and come to know maximum hop count it uses is 15 hops but My doubt is why 15 is used as maximum Hop count why not some other number 10,12 or may be 8 ?

Comment: You seem to have asked a *lot* of questions about networking lately on SO, but most of these are not programming-related and so are off-topic. Perhaps you could find a more appropriate place to ask these questions, e.g. http://superuser.com or http://serverfault.com - that way your questions won't get down-voted/closed and you may get better answers.

Comment: Thanks @Paul R for Your suggestion .Is there any way I can move these questions to  superuser.com or serverfault.com?

Comment: Yes - you can hit the `flag` link on a question and ask a moderator to migrate the question to somewhere more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that `15` is `16 - 1`, that is `2^4 - 1` or put it otherwise: the biggest unsigned value that holds in 4 bits of information.

However, the [`metric`](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/rip.htm#Metric) field is 4 bytes long. And the value `16` denotes *infinity*.

I can only guess, but I would say that it allows fast checks with a simple bit mask operation to determine whether the `metric` is *infinity* or not.

Now the real question might be: "Why is the `metric` field 4 bytes long when apparently, only five bits are used ?" and for that, I have no answer.

Answer (score 1):

Protocols often make arbitrary decision. RIP is a very basic (and rather old protocol). You should keep that in mind when reading about it. As said above, the max hop count will be a 4 byte field, where 16  is equivalent to infinity. 10 is not a power of 2 number. 8 was probably deemed too small to reach all the routers.

The rationale behind keeping the maximum hop count low is the count to infinity problems. Higher max hop counts would lead to a higher convergence time. (I'll leave you to wikipedia count to infinity problem). Certain versions of RIP use split horizon, which addresses this issue).

Comment: Thanks for your Response .but can put light on it ,I mean is it really to do with count to infinity problem?

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: The count to infinity problem is the reason why the number is small. It doesn't explain why the number is 15 instead of 12.

Comment: 12 isn't a power of 2, which makes it more complex to express (ex: you can't check if the number is infinity if all 1), so you're limited to 8 or 16 (well 7 and 15), 3 or 4 bytes. The exact number they chose is an arbitrary decision which I'm assuming was based on studying the topology of the internet at the time, and the average hop count.